# Excel::Writer::XLSX cells (with date and time) need to be refreshed

Tags: perl, excel

I can successfully create xlsx from the results of a DBI query with the Excel::Writer::XLSX package.

The only trouble is the date and time cells, when opened in Excel 2010, need to be refreshed i.e. `F2 <enter>` to display properly.

Example displayed: `2012-12-02 17:48:33.000` when spreadsheet is opened

Once refreshed   :  `02/12/2012 17:49`  desired format after `F2 <enter>`

I would be grateful for any hints/guidance on what could cause this and if this issue can be resolved within my Perl script?

Many thanks...

PS Automatic calculations are enabled, StrawberryPerl 5.16 on Win 7

**UPDATE:** For the sake of completeness and as it may be of help to others: I was using the following construct to write records from a query which could be plain strings or datetime.

If one muff's either the regex capturing the date, or the `sprintf` to put it in the proper format string required by the `write_excel_date` method, a plain string is written to the cell. That was my problem.

```
if ( $item =~ qr[(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.000] ) {
    my $date = sprintf "%4d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6;
    $worksheet->write_date_time( $row, $col++, $date, $date_format);
}
else {
    $worksheet->write( $row, $col++, $item );
}
```

Comment: Are you using `$worksheet->write_date_time()` and an appropriate format?

Comment: Yes. As commented below following john's post, my script fails to capture the date and time "tokens" and thus just prints it as a string. Strange since it would seem pretty straightforward... Got to work on it a little more... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write the dates using the Worksheet `write_date_time()` method then you shouldn't have to refresh them in Excel since they are just formatted numbers and don't require re-cacluation.

If however, you are writing the dates as strings then you would need to do something in Excel to convert them to dates. You shouldn't need to do that though since Excel::Writer::XLSX provides a dedicated method for writing dates:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook    = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'date_example.xlsx' );
my $worksheet   = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $date_format = $workbook->add_format( num_format => 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm' );

# Increase the column width to make the output clearer.
$worksheet->set_column( 'A:A', 20 );

# Write the date.
$worksheet->write_date_time( 'A1', '2012-12-02T17:48:33.000', $date_format );

__END__
```

[image]

See the [Dates and Times](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm#DATES_AND_TIME_IN_EXCEL) section of the Excel::Writer::XLSX documentation for a detailed explanation of how to deal with dates.

Comment: Your basic example of course works. My error is failing to test and capture when a date&time received from my DBI query, the else clause just printing as a regular string. </ br>Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, John and kudos for this great module (and its predecessors...)

Answer (score 0):

what about adding a line of VBA code to the `Workbook_Open()` event?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Application.Calculate

End Sub
```

would that meet your needs?

Comment: Though about it for a few seconds but figured I was probably making some basic error. But thanks for your suggestion.